# Get all positions in a python 2D array at a distance from a given position

Tags: python, arrays, distance

Given an Python 2D array

```
a = [[1, 0, 0], 
     [*0, 0, 0*], 
     [*0*, **0**, *1*], 
     [*0, 1, 0*]]
```

An example possition is [2,1] say [x,y] the bold position. What I am after is the positions around the given position at a particular distance say 1. And it should return all the position marked in italics.

Now I am doing this in a very rudimentary way traversing throught the two dimentional array

```
for (i, row) in enumerate(a):
  for (j, value) in enumerate(row):
    print(i, j, value)
```

and picking up all value for

```
[x,y-1]
[x,y+1]
[x-1,y-1]
[x-1,y]
[x-1,y+1] 
[x+1,y-1]
[x+1,y]
[x+1,y+1]
```

Now this does what I want, be it uneconomically and was wondering if there is a better way to achieve this especially if the requirements gets to for a distance more than one

Any direction would be appreciated

Comment: That is not an array, that is a list.